Ask permission to publish article based on work from a different school?
I want to publish an article based on my master's from a previous school. I am now in a phd program at a new school. Do I need to ask my new supervisor for permission to publish the article? The master's was in political science, and my new discipline is history.
Unfortunately, my old school will not put any master's thesis into ProQuest so my only hope of sharing the results is by publishing an article.
From reading other posts, I gather that I use my new school as my affiliation but mention where the work was done.

You could also put your thesis up on some kind of repository, I don't know if there is an appropriate *XiV.

If your work is your's alone and you don't need co-authors then you can publish as you like. If it was funded by the university you should acknowledge that. If others are validly co-authors they need to be included in the paper and in the decision.
Your new supervisor isn't involved and need not be asked, but might have advice.
Affiliation is a bit tricker. My opinion is that it is your new school. Some would say that it should be the old one, especially if the funding issue arises. If the article is new but based on the masters thesis then almost certainly be the current school.
There might be some places that claim IP for all work done there. In such a case a lawyer might need consulting or an IP office at the old school.
Some fields, but not likely political science, also have security considerations that require lawyers and such.

For quite a number of journals, the affiliation issue is actually answered (to some extent, and to the limit of understanding of 'majority of the work') in the author guidelines  or publisher editorial policies (see e.g. https://www.springer.com/us/editorial-policies/authorship-principles?srsltid=AfmBOoqifczZ6Pt7s_xer-bFaezRuxNBHiYD2fJm8_yPoU6OMYrjkPi8#toc-49266 or https://www.nature.com/ncomms/submit/how-to-submit. )
